# how to memoize my code for finding power of a number

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion

I am trying to find the power of a number using recursion but there's a lot of repeatation in my recursion tree. Please help me out, how can I use memoization in my code to increase the efficiency of my code.

```
double myPow(double x, int n) {
        if(n==0)
            return 1;
        if(n==-1)
            return 1/x;
        if(n==1)
            return x;
        if(n%2==0)
            return myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2);
        else
            if(n>0)
                return myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2+1);
            else
                return myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2-1);
    }

**Constraints:**

-100.0 < x < 100.0
-2^31 <= n <= 2^31-1
-10^4 <= x^n <= 10^4
```

Comment: there are two kinds of superflous repetitions in your code. One is for a single call to eg `myPow(3.141,20)` the other is for multiple calls. The first you can aviod easily, while the second I have doubts whether it is worth the effort. Which one are you concerned about?

Comment: It will really be helpful if you tell both of them.

Answer (score 0):

I usually take one of two approaches to solve a problem like this.

1. Pass along a map to cache parameter-> result pairs
2. Recurse upwards, this can normally lead to a single "line" of recursive calls, rather than branching.

For 1, you could modify your code like this:

```
double myPow(double x, int n, map<int, double> &cache) {
    if(n==0)
        return 1;
    if(n==-1)
        return 1/x;
    if(n==1)
        return x;
    auto it = cache.find(n);
    if(it != cache.end()){
        return it->second;
    }
    double result = 0;
    if(n%2==0)
        result = myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2);
    else
        if(n>0)
            result = myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2+1);
        else
            result = myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2-1);

    cache.emplace(n,result);
    return result;
}
```

For approach 2 you could start calculating at n=1 and recurse upwards to the passed parameter.

Comment: Am I missing something here or shouldn't the cache be more like `map<pair<int, double>, double>`, because the cached value depends on both the exponent `n` and the base `x`? Your cache only seems to take the exponent into account.

Comment: indeed your cache is only for the exponent. And thats not needed if you rearrange `result = myPow(x,n/2)*myPow(x,n/2)` to `temp = myPow(x,n/2);  result = temp*temp;` (plus taking care of the odd-even cases)

Comment: @Striezel, yes, I would make a wrapper where I declared the map and then pass it in for this specific base.  Of course it is possible to cache the pair, but the likelihood of a cache hit on a double it very low.